Could not add custom controls to storybooks in react-native
I am trying to add custom controls to storybook to switch the template. I get no error but I can't see the actions.
export const decorators = [withThemeProvider];

export const globalTypes = {
  theme: {
    name: 'Toggle theme',
    description: 'Global theme for components',
    defaultValue: 'light',
    toolbar: {
      icon: 'circlehollow',
      items: ['light', 'dark'],
      showName: true,
      dynamicTitle: true
    }
  }
}

const preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

